# Failed to download C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpKwaqK8/GSE40435_series_matrix.txt.gz

Tags: r

code:

```
gset <- getGEO("GSE40435", GSEMatrix =TRUE, AnnotGPL=TRUE)
```

output:

```
Found 1 file(s)
GSE40435_series_matrix.txt.gz
Timeout was reached: [] Operation timed out after 120002 milliseconds with 13320192 out of 49150917 bytes receivedFile stored at:
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpKwaqK8/GSE40435_series_matrix.txt.gz
Error in downloadFile(url, destfile = destfile, mode = "wb") : 
  Failed to download C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpKwaqK8/GSE40435_series_matrix.txt.gz!
```